# how to get today date in YYYYMMDD in firebird

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

how to get today date in YYYYMMDD in firebird, I had a look on [following](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-date-literals/) but could not figured how to write this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
select replace(cast(cast('Now' as date) as varchar(10)), '-', '')
from rdb$database
```

Comment: CAST() function doesn't work for me, But EXTRACT does.

Answer (score 6):

**IN FIREBIRD v2.5.5:**

```
SELECT    LPAD( EXTRACT( YEAR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ), 4, '0' ) ||
          LPAD( EXTRACT( MONTH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ), 2, '0' ) ||
          LPAD( EXTRACT( DAY FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ), 2, '0' ) || ' ' ||
          LPAD( EXTRACT( HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ), 2, '0' ) ||
          LPAD( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ), 2, '0' ) || 
          LPAD( TRUNC( EXTRACT( SECOND FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) ), 2, '0' )
FROM      rdb$database
```

OUTPUT IS: **YYYYMMDD HHMMSS**

Answer (score 4):

This is a fully version (in Integer)

```
select  Extract(year FROM cast('NOW' as date))*10000 +
        Extract(month FROM cast('NOW' as date))*100 +
        Extract(day  FROM cast('NOW' as date)) from rdb$database
```

This is a fully version (in VARCHAR)

```
select  CAST(Extract(year FROM cast('NOW' as date))*10000 +
        Extract(month FROM cast('NOW' as date))*100 +
        Extract(day  FROM cast('NOW' as date)) AS VARCHAR(8)) from rdb$database
```

Comment: This would throw a "String Truncation" error if the date is too long  because the casting would be yyyy00.0 + mm00.0 + d.0 (float values).
It should be:

    SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CAST('NOW' AS DATE)) || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CAST('NOW' AS DATE)) || EXTRACT(DAY FROM CAST('NOW' AS DATE))
FROM RDB$DATABASE

Answer (score 2):

This Should work.

```
CREATE TABLE tab( t time, d date, ts timestamp );
INSERT INTO tab(t,d,ts) VALUES ('14:59:23', '2007-12-31', '2007-12-31 14:59');

SELECT CAST(CAST(d as varchar(10)))
FROM tab;
```