# Date to String format in Firebird

Tags: sql, datetime, firebird

How can I customize CAST (TimeStamp TO STRING) format in Firebird?

```
cast (<DateField> as VarChar(25))
```

It does not work as I want.

I do as I wish with the EXTRACT function

```
EXTRACT(day FROM <DateField>) || '.' || EXTRACT(month FROM <DateField>)||
'.' || EXTRACT(year FROM <DateField>) || ' ' || EXTRACT(hour FROM <DateField>)
```

Is there a more practical way, such as MS-SQL Server:

```
convert(nvarchar(MAX), @now, 108)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240469/how-to-get-today-date-in-yyyymmdd-in-firebird

Comment: If you need some complex formatting and don't want to bother with extracts, substrings, etc. you can use DateToStr function from open source UDF libraries like rFunc or FreeAdHoc:

http://udf.adhoc-data.de/index_eng.html

http://rfunc.sourceforge.net

FreeAdHoc UDF library is actively developed and includes most of rFunc functions with compatible names and arguments.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the query? Formatting for display purposes should be done in application, not by the database.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm trying to keep as simple as possible in my application's code. I'll do in my application as you say.

Comment: @ValMarinov - I went to the [site](http://freeadhocudf.org/index_eng.html) for the adhoc library but when you hit the download it just goes to a blank page. Would you have any idea where I could get the source code for this library? TIA.

Answer (score 2):

I *had* to do this same procedure for a project today.  I needed to perform a LIKE comparison on the date portion of a TIMESTAMP column using a user's input (formatted as dd/mm/yyyy) which could have been only partially inputted:

```
12   # any date with 12th day, December, or the year 2012
25   # 25th day of any month, or any date in 2025
12/  # 12th day of any month, or any date in December of any year
/12/ # any date in December of any year
```

This was to mirror the behavior of a Datatables text column filter while exporting the identical data to csv file.

Ugh, what a sucky task.  I have never needed to use `LIKE` on a date column in my professional career and I always advise others against it.  Life is not without compromises.

These were my findings: (I'll omit the extremely grotesque `OVERLAP()` expression that I trialled)

```
MY_STAMP
// 13.06.2019, 09:25:28.813

-- CAST(MY_STAMP AS VARCHAR(23))
// error: numeric overflow

CAST(MY_STAMP AS VARCHAR(24))
// 2019-06-13 09:25:28.8130

SUBSTRING(CAST(MY_STAMP AS VARCHAR(24)) FROM 9 FOR 2) || '/' || SUBSTRING(CAST(MY_STAMP AS VARCHAR(24)) FROM 6 FOR 2) || '/' || SUBSTRING(CAST(MY_STAMP AS VARCHAR(24)) FROM 1 FOR 4)
// 13/06/2019

EXTRACT(DAY FROM MY_STAMP) || '/' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MY_STAMP) || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_STAMP)
// 13/6/2019

SUBSTRING(100 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM MY_STAMP) FROM 2 FOR 2) || '/' || SUBSTRING(100 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MY_STAMP) FROM 2 FOR 2) || '/' || EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MY_STAMP)
// 13/06/2019
```

I assume ALL of these techniques will perform VERY poorly.  So my overriding advice is to convince the powers-to-be to rethink this action so that it can be avoided entirely.

A solid reference: [How do convert or display the date or time as string?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq314/)

In the end I elected to go with casting to varchar and substring'ing, not because of its length or performance (I didn't benchmark), purely because I felt the `100 +`  padding syntax was too wacky.

The `LPAD()` function (v2.5.5) wasn't available for our version -- we are on 2.5 at the moment, so we must be just under.

Of course, I have deviated in the delimiting character from the OP's question -- just replace my `/` with `.`.