# Select current date

Tags: firebird

I am new to Firebird. I come from a SQL Server background.

To get current date I use following query in SQL Server

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

I am looking for something similar in Firebird

Comment: Something like [Firebird current date time](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-current_timestamp.html) or even [Firebird NOW](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-now.html). Here is another post where you can even found how to format the current date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get today date in YYYYMMDD in firebird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240469/how-to-get-today-date-in-yyyymmdd-in-firebird)

Comment: @AxelH That question is how to produce a specific formatted string of a date, so not a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select 'Now' from rdb$database
-- returns 'Now'
select cast('Now' as date) from rdb$database
-- returns e.g. 2008-08-13
select cast('now' as time) from rdb$database
-- returns e.g. 14:20:19.6170
select cast('NOW' as timestamp) from rdb$database
-- returns e.g. 2008-08-13 14:20:19.6170
```

Shorthand syntax for the last three statements:

```
select date 'Now' from rdb$database
select time 'now' from rdb$database
select timestamp 'NOW' from rdb$database
```

Comment: Be aware of the caveat documented in the Firebird documentation of ['now'](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-contextvars.html#fblangref25-contextvars-now): the shorthand casts (ie `timestamp'now'`) determine the value at parse time, so a prepared statement that is reused will have a stable value even if it is reused hours after it was prepared.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the string-based solution in the [answer of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954498/466862), Firebird supports the SQL standard functions [`CURRENT_DATE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-contextvars-current-date), [`CURRENT_TIME`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-contextvars-current-time), and [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-contextvars-current-timestamp) (and with Firebird 2.5.9 and Firebird 3.0.5 in anticipation of introduction of time zones in Firebird 4: `LOCALTIME` and `LOCALTIMESTAMP`). The Firebird documentation sometimes refers to them as ['context variables'](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-contextvars).

There is a difference between `'now'` and the `CURRENT_xxx` functions: the `CURRENT_xxx` when used in PSQL code will be stable (same value) for the duration of execution of the outermost routine, while `'now'` will be evaluated individually.